# Java eclipse WindowBuilder, change look and feel

Tags: java, eclipse, look-and-feel, windowbuilder

im coding a program using windowbuilder in eclipse. I would like to have help with changing the design (Look and feel) from metal to windows. How would i do that? thank you

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html

Comment: @mKorbel For some reason your link does not show a correct article

Answer (score 18):

In Eclipse go to

*Window > Preferences > WindowBuilder > Swing > LookAndFeel*

and tick

*Apply choosen LookAndFeel in main() method*.

This way whenever you change the look and feel in WindowBuilder's design view, it will be applied in the code.

Answer (score 5):

the Swing call is:

```
try {
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Error setting native LAF: " + e);
}
```

i recall in swt the window trims will change naturally when you cycle through the themes since the widgets are actually native to the os. are you using Swing or SWT?

Answer (score 2):

That has nothing to with WindowBuilder.

Please read Swing tutorial on Swing Look And Feel at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Comment: Actually, it does, though I don't think the question made it clear enough.  The WindowBuilder toolbar has a dropdown that allows you to change look and feel, but it does not actually modify the source like most other toolbar commands do, just the preview.  Mohammad's answer above fixes this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I had tried setting WIndow Builder to use the system look and feel in preferences, but it still did not work, but simgineer's solution did. I would add to simgineer's post the specific place to add the code, as well as the tags you should use to hide the code from the Window Builder parser. In you main application window...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {                
    // hide>>$
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error setting native LAF: " + e);
    }
    // $hide<<$

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // generated code ...
        }
    });
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BiatApp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BiatApp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BiatApp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BiatApp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Support the answer with few explanation.