# Java Swing look like Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I'm using WindowBuilder Pro in Eclipse 4.3 to play with Swing. When I run my program, the font and buttons are not the native Windows look and feel. They seem to default to the 'Nimbus' look and feel. How to solve?

Comment: We need some more info..

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you want to use the System Look and Feel, which defaults to the native OS look and feel.

Take a look at [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for more details

Comment: His question is a bit more specific than setting the LAF in Java, his question is about Eclipse WindowBuilder.

Comment: @John And how does that change the need for the OP to actually open the source code and change it?

Comment: The change in the source code will not be reflected in the Eclipse Window Builder editor. Sorry, was a bit too critical.

Comment: @John I'm a bit jumpy also - sorry :P - One day, the OP will leave the WindowBuilder, when that day comes, they'll want this information...besides, it's always nice to know what's going under the hood ;)

Comment: I used to program GUI's in Java blind. I'd just code up the whole thing, crossed my fingers, and hope it would show correctly. I had a lot of pre-made classes of my own and some good practices.

I have a [bad?] habit of telling people to just abstract away Swing. I myself no longer need the skill I used to have so I've lapsed to just using Window Builder in the 2x times a year I need to write a GUI.

Comment: @john I, personally, use NetBeans GUI editor most of the time, but most of the power though, comes from understanding how an UI is put together by hand. There are things that can be done faster by hand and things that can't. I don't dispell the power of these tools, but they are just tools.

Answer (score 1):

GUI building is complex in Java. It is a shame in Java that even the good tools are complex.

For Eclipse Window Builder, you may find the included link useful for how to set the LAF.

[Java eclipse WindowBuilder, change look and feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046191/java-eclipse-windowbuilder-change-look-and-feel)

Or google "change look-and-feel in eclipse window builder"