# Eclipse Window Builder appearence

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, look-and-feel, windowbuilder

I'm learning Java Swing by writing this application and editing in Window Builder, but what I can see is that the appearance of application when I run it is different than the one I edit in Window Builder. To be specific, the one in Window Builder I like more. I checked up for some kind of skins in Window Builder and selected "Nimbus". Can I make something so that application is same look like when I run it as the one in Window Builder? I'm using Eclipse.

First one is test in Window Builder, second is when I'm running the application.

[image: test in Window Builder]

[image: when I Run application]

Comment: Sorry SS2 is here http://i.imgur.com/AoqSV80.png

Answer (score 0):

you can activate different Look and Feels in Swing Applications:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html

I guess thats missing in your running application.

```
import javax.swing.UIManager.*;

try {
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046191/java-eclipse-windowbuilder-change-look-and-feel)

In Eclipse go to

Window > Preferences > WindowBuilder > Swing > LookAndFeel

and check

Apply choosen LookAndFeel in main() method.