# Eclipse WindowBuilder is not accurate

Tags: java, eclipse, look-and-feel, windowbuilder

When I design a JDialog (here using JGoodies FormLayout) there is a big different between design time and runtime. Runtime is the bottom one with Nimbus LookAndFeel applied. Is it possible to apply Nimbus on design time or how should I make a more "responsive" GUI?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12933980/274350 for how to apply the chosen WindowBuilder LookAndFeel to program at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. Not that this question was how to apply LaF in runtime, but you lead me to the answer anyway.

Comment: Oh, yes, you want to change the design-time view.  Glad I could help, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. To apply LaF in design mode just choose it from toolbar above the designer.

[image]